# Working with multiple databases in Rails6 and problem with switching databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-replication, ruby-on-rails-6

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :follower) do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :primary) do
    # slow write operation
  end

  query = User.all # this is reading from primary, not follower database!
end
```

I do not see this problems if I am using roles to switch the connection however with roles I am not able to use multiple followers which is what I wanted in the first place.

I am also noticing that weird things are happening with DB connection counts. Is Rails 6 really addressing those things properly?